# Use of undeclared type 'AgendaTableView'

Tags: ios

I have this problem: Use of undeclared type 'AgendaTableView'

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var barItem: SearchBar = SearchBar()
    barItem.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)
    var atv: AgendaTableView = (swipeView.currentItemView as! AgendaTableView)
    barItem.searchReloadTableDelegate = atv
    barItem.listArr = atv.listArr
    barItem.listDic = atv.listDic
    self.view!.addSubview(barItem)
```

How can I fix?

Comment: where is the class AgendaTableView is located?

Comment: I used this: https://github.com/2hanson/SearchBar

Comment: Replace AgendaTableView  with your TableView class

Comment: Now I have this errors: http://imgur.com/MUjXboj

Comment: use as! MainTableViewController instead of AgendaTableView

Comment: I don't understand sorry

Comment: Can u post full code so i can understand it.

Comment: Read my comment below :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var parser = NSXMLParser()
var posts = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var title1 = NSMutableString()
var date = NSMutableString()
var link = NSMutableString()

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var barItem: SearchBar = SearchBar()
    barItem.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)
    var atv: MainTableViewController = (swipeView.currentItemView as! MainTableViewController)
    barItem.searchReloadTableDelegate = atv
    barItem.listArr = atv.listArr
    barItem.listDic = atv.listDic
    self.view!.addSubview(barItem)
```